# Firebase database is being updated at one node but is not affecting the other node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two siblings namely "intents" and "messages". when I update the messages fields it gets done properly but one the same procedure is done with intents fields, no change occurs. Below is the android-java code for the same.

```
    IntentMessage testIntentMessage = new IntentMessage("Hello test intent", "Hello test intent");
    FriendlyMessage tempMessage = new FriendlyMessage("namastey", "india", "http://imgsdown.1mobile.com/group1/M00/C1/21/S36rZla-KYqAV08jAABUIgbzI-E596.png","543587653");
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("intents").child("-sjhfdvshv").setValue(testIntentMessage);
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("messages").child("-KUVR-MkLOVwNkx6nm-_").setValue(tempMessage);
```

Below is my firebase database JSON file after above commands are executed:

```
{
  "intents" : {
    "-kjuvhsjkv" : {
      "intentFields" : "testIntentFields 1",
      "intentName" : "testIntentName 2"
    },
    "-sjhfdvshv" : {
      "intentFields" : "testIntentFields",
      "intentName" : "testIntentName"
    }
  },
  "messages" : {
    "-KUVR-MkLOVwNkx6nm-_" : {
      "name" : "india",
      "photoUrl" : "http://imgsdown.1mobile.com/group1/M00/C1/21/S36rZla-KYqAV08jAABUIgbzI-E596.png",
      "text" : "namastey",
      "timeStamp" : "543587653"
    }
  }
}
}
```

The real problem is :
when everything is alright with "messages" node, why is the "intents" node not being updated?
Given that I have made the `IntentMessage` class in the same way as `FriendlyMessage` class

Comment: Probably because of the database rules, please post them. Also check the logcat, if there's a problem with the setValue, the firebase will print a warning message in the logcat.

Comment: Yes @Wilik sir, you are right, I didn't mention the rules for "intents" in the "rules" section of firebase. Now I am receiving the data. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome @Aakash Bansal , BTW please accept your own answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem as commented by Wilik, I didn't mention the rules for "Intents" section in the "rules" section of the database. Now I'm getting proper data.